# Disable password expiration on VMware vcenter appliance?

Tags: linux, vmware

How do you disable password expiration and clear password history for VMware vcenter appliance?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done using change user password expiry information tool like this

`chage -M -1 root; echo "" > /etc/security/opasswd`

man -> https://linux.die.net/man/1/chage

Comment: Another option to reset the root password: https://kb.vmware.com/kb/2147144

Comment: Once it has been reset, you can then change the expiration with the following link: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vcsa.doc/GUID-C63C82F1-D430-4710-8B92-177A79D3DE65.html